# Braintree payment

Tags: ecommerce, payment-gateway

I need to use Braintree payment gateway (https://www.braintreepayments.com/), made by Paypal

Is there any commerce modules or plugins available to support this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No e-commerce modules available for EE currently come bundled with Braintree gateway plugins, but all support the development of custom gateways. So I'd choose your module based on the features you need, then tackle the Braintree gateway after.